# Can't import project into Eclipse - "Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly"

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I was trying to clone a project in Eclipse and after copying it into the same directory, I got a lot of build path errors, even after deleting the copy of the project. So, I decided to back up the original project, delete it from the directory and try importing it again. However, when I try to import it I get a "Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly" error. I have looked extensively on this and other sites and found no solution, I tried deleting the .gradle folder as well as several others, to no avail. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I managed to get the project back into Eclipse, by clicking Import > General > Existing Project Into Workspace and then selecting 'Search for nested projects'. However when I try to run the program, it gives the same error and beneath that says 'Update Gradle Classpath for <Project Name>'

Answer (score 0):

It didn't fix the problem, but I managed to find a workaround by creating a new LibGDX project with the same name and then copying the 'src' folders from each subproject into their respective folders in the new project. Their were still a few problems with the android version, but once I picked an android target and added 'gen' to the source folders in the build path, it worked.